# Extracting a tree structure

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How do I retrieve a hierarchical tree structure with a linq query and EF?

My database has tables for `Tab` which is 1-to-Many to `TabGroupBox` which is 1-to-Many to `FieldDetail`

I would like to retrieve only portions of the structure based on some criteria.

Say, I have the following in the database:

Tab (Name)

```
"Tab1"
"Tab2"
"Tab3"
```

TabGroupBox (Tab.Name, Name)

```
"Tab1", "Group1"
"Tab2", "Group2"
"Tab1", "Group3"
```

FieldDetail: (TabGroupBox.Name, Name, FieldStatus)

```
"Group1", "Field1", "Good1"
"Group2", "Field2", "Good2"
"Group3", "Field3", "Bad"
"Group1", "Field4", "Good3"
"Group1", "Field5", "Bad"
```

If the criteria is for the FieldStatus to contain "Good", then the result I'm looking for is:

```
Tab1
-Group1
--Field1
--Field4
Tab2
-Group2
--Field2
```

However, at the moment can only seem to get either

```
Field1
Field2
Field4
```

or a duplication of tabs corresponding to the fields

```
Tab1
Tab1
Tab2
```

A sample of my non-working query:

```
Tabs.SelectMany(x => x.TabGroupBoxes.SelectMany(y => y.FieldDetails).Where(z =>
    (z.FieldDetailType.Contains("Good")
))
.Select(x => x.TabGroupBox.Tab)
```

I've also tried making use of `.Include()` but no success

Additionally, if possible, I'd like to project the db models onto my view models within the query, but this is not as important as above.

Comment: Looks like you should create a database view using Common Table Expression and map the view into EF.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek How does your suggestion address my problem? I can put together a query in Sql and Linq that gives me a flat table, but that is not what I'm after.

Comment: hey grt question -deceptively simple until you look at the fact that you want a subset of the lower leaves returned. my gut feel says that linq may become cumbersome to do this, but never say never -let me have a delve

Comment: hmmm - too big a brain tease to fit between tea breaks. my instinct tells me you'll need to look at some combo of .Any() and .RemoveAll(). will monitor thread as am interested to see a neat result in linq alone (obviuosly, a code loop solution would work, but that's not the gameplan i guess)

Comment: @jimtollan You're right, a code loop solution works, and in fact I implemented it successfully but it's not as nice and tidy as I would've liked it. I'll post up my looping solution a bit later, but I want to see if something else comes of this question first.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is the following.

```
context.FieldDetails
       .Include(fieldDetail => fieldDetail.GroupBox.Tab) // Use eager loading.
       .Where(fieldDetail => fieldDetail.FieldDetailType.Contains("Good")))
       .AsEnumerable() // We will do the remaining work client side.
       .Select(fieldDetail => fieldDetail.GroupBox.Tab)
       .Distinct() // Get rid of duplicate tabs.
       .ToList()
```

What is not easily possible is to retrieve a collection of related entites partially, for example only `Group1` but not `Group3` for `Tab1`. If you could do this it would cause some headaches. What if you commit changes for `Tab1`? Should `Group3` get deleted because it is not present in the collection of groups? Should it stay because you did not load it in the first place? If you think about it for some time you will realize that the ability to partially load collections of related entities would add a lot of complexity and make the behavior very non-intuitive in some cases.

If this is not enough you might be able to create views or functions in the database and map these to your model but I have not used the Entity Framework for more than two years and did not follow the development so I can not provide you more details how to approach this.